# Why does Python not allow my comments to be indented at the proper level?

Tags: python, syntax, comments, indentation

I have Python code that looks like this:

```
'''
a) comments
'''
try:
  do_stuff()

'''
b) comments
'''
except Error:
  do_stuff()
```

but it complains that the (b) comments are a syntax error - it forces me to indent it like this:

```
'''
a) comments
'''
try:
  do_stuff()

  '''
  b) comments
  '''
except Error:
  do_stuff()
```

Why is this, and how do I get around it?  I want the (b) comments to be at the same level with the "except" statement they describe.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, the triple quotes are used for multiline strings or [docstrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), which appear only at the beginning of the function/class/module that you are documenting.

When not writing docstrings, I would recommend that you use the normal comment syntax:

`# this is a comment`

Also, if you want to have docstrings, convention dictates that you use triple double quotes: `"""`, not `'''`

Answer (score 3):

The triple quotes are actually strings, not comments.

So you need to indent the strings accordingly, (since every colon (`:`) must be immediately followed by an indented block)

Answer (score 0):

First, it is not the comments, but strings, so what you are really trying to do is different. Indent and dedent are like opening and closing brackets in some other languages, so what you are really doing (in PHP-like syntax):

```php
try {
    $some_string = 'a) comments';
    do_stuff();
} // notice closing bracket, which works like decreased indent
$some_string = 'b) comments';
catch (Error $e) {
    do_stuff();
}
```

Try using real comments instead:

```py
# a) comments
try:
    do_stuff()

# b) comments
except Error:
    do_stuff()
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/CxU56R